# How to color a field in tree view with today as filter

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am  new to openERP.  I am working on changing the color in tree view for those record whose due_date is less then Today.  Those record should be in red color.

I am not able to get the current date as filter in tree view.

xml what I need but **not working**:

```
<tree colors="blue:Due_date < Today()" string="Invoice">
                    <field name="Due_date" />
                    <field name="date_invoice"/>
                    <field name="state"/>
                </tree>
```

**Working code**

```
<tree colors="blue:state == 'open'" string="Invoice">
                    <field name="partner_id" groups="base.group_user"/>
                    <field name="date_invoice"/>                      
                    <field name="state"/>
                </tree>
```

I tried with

```
context_today()
```

and

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Nothing work.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .xml side `<, >, <=, >=` is not supported. So we need to use `&lt;, &gt;, &lt;= and &gt;=`

This will work, try this,

```
<tree colors="blue:due_date &lt; current_date;" string="Invoice">
    <field name="Due_date" />
    <field name="date_invoice"/>
    <field name="state"/>
</tree>
```

Comment: Great.  Its working. However, it is coloring for the lines which are did not have 'Due_date'.  Any suggestion for me to skip those data without date.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, it's work than you may accept answer and also upvote for it. You can also use `&gt.` And for skip data without date, use filter. That will shows only data which has due date. Thanks

Comment: how to add current_date +days ?? for exemple 1 day

Comment: @Caludio You can add new function field in object which value must be store in database. Afterwards, you may try it on condition view side.

Comment: how to do that ? have you an example please !

Answer (score -1):

This will work, try this:

```
<tree colors="red:due_date &lt; datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(23,59,59));" string="Invoice"></tree>
```