# How to color a single field in tree view in openerp based on a condition?

Tags: odoo

The purpose is to color a single field and not the entire fields in the tree. For eg: I have a product line and i need to color the product field alone as red based on a condition.

Comment: Check out this might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699625/how-to-color-a-field-in-tree-view-with-today-as-filter/25718627#25718627

Comment: U mentioned about using a filter to single out a field for coloring. Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: What I meant is I want to color only a single field and not the entire line. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can try:  **colors="red: actual > budget"** in tag tree